# Problem on a set of all $3 \times 3$ real upper triangular matrices with all diagonal entries $=1$,

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $W$ be the set of all $3 \times 3$ real upper triangular matrices with diagonal entries $1$ and let $B = (b_{ij})$ be a $3 \times 3$ real matrix trhat satisfies $AB = BA$ for all $A \in W$ then choose the correct statement(s)$-$

$a$. Every $A$ in $W$ has an inverse which is in $W$

$b$. $b_{12} = 0$

$c$. $b_{13} = 0$

$d$. $b_{23} = 0$

I tried to take matrix

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & a & b \\\
0 & 1 & c \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and 
$$ B = \begin{pmatrix}
d & e & f \\\
g & h & i \\
j & k & l
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then using the relation $AB = BA$, tried to solve the equations but got nothing useful.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you trying to prove (a)-(d)? Also notice that (b)-(d) together say that $B$ is lower triangular; I think the key to proving this part is that you can pick specific $A$'s in $W$ and we have to have $AB=BA$.

Answer (score 1):

To prove (a) just take an arbitrary matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&a&b\\0&1&c\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ from $W$ and compute its inverse using the classic Gauss-Jordan elimination method (or any other method).

SPOILER:

> The inverse of $A$ should be $$\begin{bmatrix}1&-a&-b+ca\\0&1&-c\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ which is also in $W$.

To prove (b)-(d) you just have to choose a specific matrix $A$ from $W$ and compare the entries of $AB$ and $BA$.

SPOILER:

> Try $$A:=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: I'm getting $B$ matrix an upper triangular matrix.

Comment: Yes so that will impose restrictions on what the entries of $B$ can be, then you can try choosing other matrices $A$ to see if the top entries should be zero (or some of them).

Comment: I'm not getting any idea about $B$ by multiplying matrices. How can I find the nature of $B$ for general case.

Comment: After doing the matrix I suggest above, make the reductions on the entries of $B$ that you can, then try other $A$ matrices like $$\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: B matrices I'm getting, don't have their entries $b_{12} ,b_{13}, b_{23} =0$, necessarily. So only option a is correct $?$